# Взаимодействие flash + .net

Tags: asp.net, flash, .net, c#

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажете какие способы взаимодействия есть в этой связке и если можно - ссылки на литературу.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на сервере работает ASP.NET, а на клиент Flash, то для общения между ними нужен какой-либо протокол обмена, понятный для обоих. Варианты такие:

- WSDL
- JSON
- AMF

Для всех вариантов есть либо встроенная поддержка, либо можно найти сторонние библиотеки, добавляющие поддержку.

Comment: Спасибо. А какой способ и с какой библиотекой наиболее удобен и прост в кодировании? Из вашего личного опыта?

Comment: Про AMF я ничего не могу сказать. А WSDL и JSON в равной степени просты и удобны.

Comment: Привет, а не подскажешь работает ли wsdl во проекте action Sript? или он только под flex?